# Extract string between two patterns (inclusive) while conserving the format

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gsub

I have a file in the following format

```
cat test.txt
id1,PPLLTOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,PPLRTOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACK
id3,PPLRTOMcccccccccccJACK
```

I am trying to identify and print the string between `TOM` and `JACK` including these two strings, while maintaining the first column `FS=,`

Desired output:

```
id1,TOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,TOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACK
id3,TOMcccccccccccJACK
```

So far I have tried `gsub`:

```
awk -F"," 'gsub(/.*TOM|JACK.*/,"",$2) && !_[$0]++' test.txt > out.txt
```

and have the following output

```
id1 aaaaaaaaaaa
id2 bbbbbbbbbbb
id3 ccccccccccc
```

As you can see I am getting close but not able to include `TOM` and `JACK` patterns in my output. Plus I am also losing the original `FS`. What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are changing a field (`$2`) which causes awk to reconstruct the record using the value of `OFS` as the field separator and so in this case changing the commas to spaces.

Never use `_` as a variable name - using a name with no meaning is just slightly better than using a name with the wrong meaning, just pick a name that means something which, in this case is `seen` but idk what you are trying to do when using that in this context.

`gsub()` and `sub()` do not support capture groups so you either need to use `match()`+`substr()`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} match($2,/TOM.*JACK/){$2=substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)} 1' file
id1,TOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,TOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACK
id3,TOMcccccccccccJACK
```

or use GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} match($2,/TOM.*JACK/,a){$2=a[0]} 1' file
id1,TOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,TOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACK
id3,TOMcccccccccccJACK
```

or for `gensub()`:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=gensub(/.*(TOM.*JACK).*/,"\\1","",$2)} 1' file
id1,TOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,TOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACK
id3,TOMcccccccccccJACK
```

The main difference between the `match()` and `gensub()` solutions is how they would behave if TOM appeared twice on the line:

```
$ cat file
id1,PPLLfooTOMbarTOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,PPLRTOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACKfooJACKbar
id3,PPLRfooTOMbarTOMcccccccccccJACKfooJACKbar
$
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} match($2,/TOM.*JACK/,a){$2=a[0]} 1' file
id1,TOMbarTOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,TOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACKfooJACK
id3,TOMbarTOMcccccccccccJACKfooJACK
$
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=gensub(/.*(TOM.*JACK).*/,"\\1","",$2)} 1' file
id1,TOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,TOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACKfooJACK
id3,TOMcccccccccccJACKfooJACK
```

and just to show one way of stopping at the first instead of the last JACK on the line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} match($2,/TOM.*JACK/,a){$2=gensub(/(JACK).*/,"\\1","",a[0])} 1' file
id1,TOMbarTOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,TOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACK
id3,TOMbarTOMcccccccccccJACK
```

Answer (score 1):

Use capture groups to save the parts of the line you want to keep. Here's how to do it with `sed`

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*,\).*\(TOM.*JACK\).*/\1\2/' <test.txt > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to do the following?

```
$ cat test.txt
id1,PPLLTOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACKABCD
id2,PPLRTOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACKDFCC
id3,PPLRTOMcccccccccccJACKSDER

$ cat test.txt | sed -e 's/,.*TOM/,TOM/g' | sed -e 's/JACK.*/JACK/g'
id1,TOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,TOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACK
id3,TOMcccccccccccJACK
$
```

This should work as long as the TOM and JACK do not repeat themselves.

Comment: That may behave undesirably if a line contained `TOMabcBOB`.

Comment: as long as TOM and JACK exist at the expected places this should work. Example of what might not work?

Comment: A line like `id,fooTOMabcBOB`, if it can exist in the input, would undesirably be changed to `id,TOMabcBOB`.

Comment: Me neither but it stopped me using a similar solution in my awk answer :-).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(.*,\).*\(TOM.*JACK\).*/\1\2/' <oldfile >newfile
```

Output:

```
id1,TOMaaaaaaaaaaaJACK
id2,TOMbbbbbbbbbbbJACK
id3,TOMcccccccccccJACK
```